# Resend OTP on Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase-authentication

I was trying to resend OTP using firebase. For that I have used following code..

```js
 function resendOTP() {
  var number = $("#phoneCode").val() + $("#inputWebsite").val();

  window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', { // <-- Corrected placement of parenthesis
    'size': 'invisible',
    'callback': (response) => {
      firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(number, window.recaptchaVerifier).then(function(confirmationResult) {
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        coderesult = confirmationResult;
      }).catch(function(error) {
        $("#error").text(error.message);
        $("#error").show();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I can't resend OTP again with above method. How to resend OTP with firebase?

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It makes it much easier for others to read and understand quickly. I've done it for you in this instance.